Problem with Gradle in Sweet Alert Dialog Android
In my Android application, I would like to use the Sweet Alert Dialog library. Unfortunately, after correctly adding the following line in the Gradle file:
implementation 'com.github.taimoorsultani:android-sweetalert2:2.0.2'
a build error appears:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

Is there a way to solve this issue?"

Don't use Gradle 9.0, Android Studio only recommends 8.9 when creating a new project and even that has a few bugs in it that can stop building, better to use 8.7

According https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases, the latest stable version is 8.11.
I think changing the gradle version to 8.x should solve the problem.
Goto ->
Gradle -> gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.x-bin.zip

Change the build gradle version to a compatible version..
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.x.x'

EDIT :
I was able to build "com.github.taimoorsultani:android-sweetalert2:2.0.2" with below
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.11-bin.zip

Edit : As of November 2024, Gradle 9.0 is not yet officially released. The latest stable version is Gradle 8.11, so I think you should use to 8.x.

Gradle 9.0 as the version suggests via the major version change, contains breaking changes. A bug should probably be raised against the library to fixed the incompatibility with Gradle 9.0

I think as of today (12 Nov 2024) the stable version of gradle 9.x is yet to be released officially. It has many open issues  -> https://github.com/gradle/gradle/milestone/211

So I think we should wait for a official stable release.

They are fixing many issues, this issue might get resolved with stable version.
